# Integral of the complementary error function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate this integral:
$$\int{\mathrm{erfc}^2\!\left(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right) e^{ixc}} \mathrm{d}x$$
where $a$ and $c$ are parameters. Is there any way to calculate this integral or approximate it?